# CCSprite Follow User Touch

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

So far, I have made my `CCSprite` move to the location of the user's touch on the screen using `CCActionMoveTo`, however I have only got it to work when the user simply taps.

I would like the CCSprite to move when the user drags their finger, instead of just tapping and moving along with the ability to change direction as the user drags changes direction - I am fairly new to cocos2d and have search for similar questions but have been unable to find any. I have posted my code below:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    // Player sprite
    _playerSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"PlayerSprite.png"];
    _playerSprite.scale = 0.5;
    _playerSprite.position  = ccp(self.contentSize.width/2, 150);
    [self addChild:_playerSprite];
    return self;
}

-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CCActionMoveTo *actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.2f position:ccp(touchLoc.x, 150)];
    [_playerSprite runAction:actionMove];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement the touchMoved method and set your sprite position in there.  Something like this:

```
- (void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
  _playerSprite.position = touchLocation;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Knew it would be easy. Any way to delay the movement by a second or so before the sprite moves?

Comment: With these things firing all the time you will need to be careful, but you could create an action sequence with a delay time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (add a CGPoint property called previousTouchPos):

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self];
    self.previousTouchPos = touchLoc;

    CCActionMoveTo *actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:touchLoc];
    [_playerSprite runAction:actionMove];
}


-(void) touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self];
    CGPoint delta = ccpSub(touchLoc, self.previousTouchPos);

    _playerSprite.position = ccpAdd(_playerSprite.position, delta);
    self.previousTouchPos = touchLoc;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ideal use case for CCActionFollow:

https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/365/make-two-nodes-follow-each-other-in-cocos2d-30

If you use the variation where you provide the target position through a block you can use the latest touch position as target position.